# Getting eth blocks timenstamp fast

Tags: python, web3py

I downloaded all transactions for one token over the last year. Currently I have dataframe with 200000 entries. For each entry I have block number and amount transacted. Now I need to transform block number to timestamp. I know that I can do that through

```
WEB3.eth.getBlock(i).timestamp
```

However, for 200000 entries it takes 10 hours. Is there any faster method to do that?

Comment: You can run your code in parallel.

Comment: @BramVanroy thanks for the suggestion, will try that

Comment: If you are working on mainnet, you can use this tool https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/ethereum-bigquery-public-dataset-smart-contract-analytics that has API you can call from your script.